# Launching default browser without the title bar

Tags: c, windows, winapi, browser, window

I am currently working on an application in C++ that, when launched, opens the user's default browser in a window without title bar (particularly I want to get rid of all the buttons in upper right corner). I check the executable path with this piece of code:

```
HKEY Key;
LPCTSTR Key2 = TEXT("http\\shell\\open\\command");
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, Key2, 0L, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &Key);
char Path[256];
DWORD dwSize = 256;
RegQueryValueEx(Key, NULL, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)Path, &dwSize);
LPCSTR browser=Path;
```

and then pass it to `CreateProcess()`.

My question is: How should I remove the title bar of this window and wouldn't it be better to use ShellExecute and get handle with `FindWindow()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the title bar,
Get a handle on your target using FindWindow().
Change style attributes in your target window and modify it.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   HWND hWnd = NULL;
   LONG lStyle;  

   hWnd = FindWindow(0, "Google - Windows Internet Explorer");
   lStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
   lStyle &= ~WS_CAPTION; /*remove  WS_CAPTION style */
   SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);
   if(hWnd!=NULL)          
      SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED ); /*Changes style in your window */

return 0;
}
```

Both of these features will do the job, but CreateProcess is more reliable and secure function unlike ShellExecute